# Unresolved token and symbols for <alcapi.h>

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I want to create a library so I can [modify the ACLs of an Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379283(v=vs.85).aspx).
I've created an C++ project in VS 2015 (all C++ components are installed), giving me the layout for an DLL library.

I've included the sample code in the link above in my .cpp file, and included alcapi.h :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Aclapi.h>

DWORD AddAceToObjectsSecurityDescriptor(
    LPTSTR pszObjName,          // name of object
    SE_OBJECT_TYPE ObjectType,  // type of object
    LPTSTR pszTrustee,          // trustee for new ACE
    TRUSTEE_FORM TrusteeForm,   // format of trustee structure
    DWORD dwAccessRights,       // access mask for new ACE
    ACCESS_MODE AccessMode,     // type of ACE
    DWORD dwInheritance         // inheritance flags for new ACE
)
{
    DWORD dwRes = 0;
    PACL pOldDACL = NULL, pNewDACL = NULL;
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = NULL;
    EXPLICIT_ACCESS ea;
...
```

When I try to build this, I get following errors like following:

```
LNK2028 unresolved token (0A00005D) "extern "C" unsigned long __stdcall SetNamedSecurityInfoW(wchar_t *,enum _SE_OBJECT_TYPE,unsigned long,void *,void *,struct _ACL *,struct _ACL *)" (?SetNamedSecurityInfoW@@$$J228YGKPA_WW4_SE_OBJECT_TYPE@@KPAX2PAU_ACL@@3@Z) referenced in function "unsigned long __cdecl AddAceToObjectsSecurityDescriptor(wchar_t *,enum _SE_OBJECT_TYPE,wchar_t *,enum _TRUSTEE_FORM,unsigned long,enum _ACCESS_MODE,unsigned long)" (?AddAceToObjectsSecurityDescriptor@@$$FYAKPA_WW4_SE_OBJECT_TYPE@@0W4_TRUSTEE_FORM@@KW4_ACCESS_MODE@@K@Z)    
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "extern "C" unsigned long __stdcall SetNamedSecurityInfoW(wchar_t *,enum _SE_OBJECT_TYPE,unsigned long,void *,void *,struct _ACL *,struct _ACL *)" (?SetNamedSecurityInfoW@@$$J228YGKPA_WW4_SE_OBJECT_TYPE@@KPAX2PAU_ACL@@3@Z) referenced in function "unsigned long __cdecl AddAceToObjectsSecurityDescriptor(wchar_t *,enum _SE_OBJECT_TYPE,wchar_t *,enum _TRUSTEE_FORM,unsigned long,enum _ACCESS_MODE,unsigned long)" (?AddAceToObjectsSecurityDescriptor@@$$FYAKPA_WW4_SE_OBJECT_TYPE@@0W4_TRUSTEE_FORM@@KW4_ACCESS_MODE@@K@Z)
```

**The linker doesn't find the definitions for the functions declared in aclapi.h.**

What do I need to do to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start by searching for and [reading the reference for `SetNamedSecurityInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379579(v=vs.85).aspx), that will tell you what libraries you need to link with.

Comment: It's "Advapi32.dll", which I find on my computer in the System32 folder. But I can't add the reference to the project, as it's "not of a type or version current project can use". Also, is this library not a standard library that he should find without help?

Comment: To be able to use a DLL you need to link with an *import library*, in this case `advapi32.lib`. Add it in the project linker settings. Some of these import libraries are linked automatically, but not all system libraries are automatically linked.

Comment: Try to export the functions with `__declspec(dllexport) or __declspec(dllimport)`

Comment: Yes, thank you @JoachimPileborg! I needed to add advapi32.lib to 'Additional dependencies' in the Linker configuration.

Also; found it was a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148212/visual-studio-2010-library-linking-errors)

Comment: @jeroen.desmedt: Not a direct duplicate. `advapi32.lib` has a lot of symbols, but far from all. It just so happens that the linked question needed the same library, but for different symbols.